# C++ Operator Overloading Within an Already Overloaded Operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm having a bit of an issue using overloaded operators in an already overloaded operator. In my following code, I have overloaded the && operator to compare two Course objects. The operator in turn goes to a function which calls other overloaded operators to compare private object variables of that object to compare them mainly:

Code:

```
bool operator&&(const DaysOfWeek& a, const DaysOfWeek& b);
bool operator&&(const TimeInterval& a, const TimeInterval& b);
```

Now, for my question. I have been using many overloaded operators in this project, but this is the first time I have had to call overloaded operators inside other overloaded operators. Unfortunately, my overloaded operators in the code above is not being called from my isOverlap function. So my question is: why is this and how can I correct it?

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated, as I am banging my head against the wall trying to get this to work. i have included the relevent code from Course.h and the functions and overloaded operator in Course.cpp. I have bolded the appropriate lines of code that I am having irregular output for (not using my overloaded operator).

Code:

```
bool Course::isOverlap(const Course& b) const
{
    DaysOfWeek tempDays = b.getDays();
    TimeInterval tempTime = b.getTime();
    if(this->instructor==b.getInstructor() &&
        &this->days&&(&tempDays) &&
        &this->time&&(&tempTime))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

bool operator&&(const Course& a, const Course& b)
{
    if (a.isOverlap(b))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Code:

```
#ifndef COURSE_H
#define COURSE_H

#include <string>
#include "TimeInterval.h"
#include "DaysOfWeek.h"

using namespace std;

class Course
{
    public:
        Course();
        Course(const string courseCode, const string section,
            const DaysOfWeek& days, const TimeInterval& time,
            const string instructor);
        void setCourse(string courseCode, string section,
            DaysOfWeek& days, TimeInterval& time, string instructor);
        string getCourse() const;
        string getSection() const;
        DaysOfWeek getDays() const;
        TimeInterval getTime() const;
        string getInstructor() const;
        bool isOverlap(const Course& b) const;
        bool isMatch(const Course& b) const;

    private:
        string courseCode;
        string section;
        DaysOfWeek days;
        TimeInterval time;
        string instructor;
};

bool operator&&(const Course& a, const Course& b);
bool operator==(const Course& a, const Course& b);

#endif //COURSE_H
```

I have also tried replacing the code I have with:

```
bool Course::isOverlap(const Course& b) const
{
    DaysOfWeek tempDays = b.getDays();
    TimeInterval tempTime = b.getTime();
    if(instructor==b.getInstructor() &&
        days && tempDays &&
        time && tempTime)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

As a friend had suggested, but this doesn't even compile (doesn't match the arguments to the overloaded && operator).

Comment: You really don't want to overload the `&&` operator.  Do you mean to overload `==`, perhaps?

Comment: No, I mean &&. For an assignment I must use && to test for overlapping. == for exact matching.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
instructor==b.getInstructor() && days && tempDays && time && tempTime
```

is equivalent to this:

```
(((((instructor==b.getInstructor()) && days) && tempDays) && time) && tempTime)
```

First `instructor==b.getInstructor()` is evaluated, yielding a `bool`.  Then the compiler sees `&& days` and tries to find an overload of `&&` that takes a `bool` and a `DaysOfWeek`.  There isn't one, so it yields an error.

To use your overloaded `&&` alongside the built-in `&&`, you need some parentheses to force grouping of the subexpressions:

```
instructor==b.getInstructor() && (days && tempDays) && (time && tempTime)
                                 ^                ^    ^                ^
```

That said, I would strongly advise going back to your instructor and telling him that he is crazy.  Overloading the `&&` operator (or the `||` operator) is almost always wrong because it breaks the normal semantics of the operator (when overloaded, those two operators cease to short-circuit).

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much for your answer. Works perfectly now! I can't believe it was some parentheses problems, but then again I would have never thought to overload the && operator like you said. ;)

Again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
   DaysOfWeek tempDays = b.getDays();
    TimeInterval tempTime = b.getTime();
    if(this->instructor==b.getInstructor() &&
        &this->days&&(&tempDays) &&
        &this->time&&(&tempTime))
```

In the above you are using logical and for the address of `days` compared to the address of `tempDays`, you should be comparing the objects, not the addresses. Same with `time` and `tempTime`.